# Outlook 2010 , labelled ***SPAM*** yet it still comes to the inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am receiving spam email in my inbox even though it has been marked as ***Spam*** . I even elevated the filtering level to High?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mail server is probably marking the emails with ***SPAM***.  You could create a rule that automatically moves a message that contains the word ***SPAM*** in the subject to a specific folder.  If you are confident that your SPAM filter is marking email correctly, then you could move SPAM directly to Trash.

Here is a [**tutorial that explains Rules**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA010355682.aspx).